# Iterate through several lists and get a new list as a result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-merge

I have two DataFrames that look like this:

```
dfH
  TICKER  Qty     PPC        Date      PxQ     PPerc
0      C    6  4185.0  2021-11-13  25110.0  0.097416
1   AAPL   20  3058.0  2021-11-13  61160.0  0.237274
2    JPM    3  5915.0  2021-11-13  17745.0  0.068843
3     KO   15  2481.0  2021-11-13  37215.0  0.144378
4   MSFT   10  5825.6  2021-11-13  58256.0  0.226008
5     PG    5  6280.0  2021-11-13  31400.0  0.121818
6    WMT    5  5375.0  2021-11-13  26875.0  0.104263

dfMerged
Date,C,AAPL,JPM,KO,MSFT,PG,WMT
2020-11-10,2380.000,1759.000,3480.000,1601.000,3189.500,4269.000,3665.000
2020-11-11,2475.000,1798.000,3500.000,1626.000,3286.000,4352.000,3780.000
2020-11-12,2409.000,1765.000,3392.000,1590.000,3208.000,4305.000,3687.000
2020-11-13,2425.000,1770.000,3400.000,1590.000,3245.000,4322.500,3780.000
2020-11-16,2472.000,1792.000,3460.000,1600.000,3215.000,4240.000,3805.000
2020-11-17,2535.000,1810.000,3489.000,1610.000,3220.000,4300.000,3793.000
```

Like Vlookup in excel I'm trying to pick `PPerc` value from `dfH` and multiply it with the correspondent column in `dfMerged`, acummulate row values and append it in `dfMerged` as a new column. With the expression below I manage to do the math but I'm having troubles to accumulate this iteration on `dfMerged["Ind"]`, I'm just getting last iteration values.

```
for i in list(dfMerged.columns):
    if i != 'Date':
        index = (dfH[dfH["TICKER"]==i]["PPerc"].values[0] * dfMerged[i])

dfMerged["Ind"] = index



       Date       C    AAPL     JPM  ...    MSFT      PG     WMT         Ind
0    2020-11-10  2380.0  1759.0  3480.0  ...  3189.5  4269.0  3665.0  382.124817
1    2020-11-11  2475.0  1798.0  3500.0  ...  3286.0  4352.0  3780.0  394.115091
2    2020-11-12  2409.0  1765.0  3392.0  ...  3208.0  4305.0  3687.0  384.418609
3    2020-11-13  2425.0  1770.0  3400.0  ...  3245.0  4322.5  3780.0  394.115091
4    2020-11-16  2472.0  1792.0  3460.0  ...  3215.0  4240.0  3805.0  396.721672
```

Comment: Will you please show a sample dataframe containg your expected output?

Comment: On DF2 I´d like to have a new colum calculated like this

df1[C][PPerc] * df2[C] + df1[AAPL][PPerc] * df2[AAPL] + df1[JPM][PPerc] * df2[JPM]

I´m trying to build and index from a portfolio allocation, and determine how it evolved over time.

Comment: So, for AAPL, would you multiply 10 (`df1[C][PPerc]`) by _each value_ of `df2[C]`? `10 * 2380.0`, `10 * 2475.0`, `10 * 2409.0` etc., and do that for each symbol?

Comment: For AAPL , pick DF1 AAPL PPerc = 10  and then multiply it on all values con AAPL column en DF2 , then do the same with the other Tickers and finally came up with a new column with all values added,

Answer (score 0):

If I you understand correctly, this works:

```py
new_col = sum([df2[symbol] * df1['PPerc'][i] for i, symbol in enumerate(df1['TICKER'])])
```

Output:

```
>>> new_col
0    76190.0
1    77730.0
2    75660.0
3    75950.0
4    77240.0
5    78340.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I´m not getting that result, I get a repeated result on every row.

           Date       C    AAPL     JPM  ...    MSFT      PG     WMT           Ind
0    2020-11-10  2380.0  1759.0  3480.0  ...  3189.5  4269.0  3665.0  877634.20095
1    2020-11-11  2475.0  1798.0  3500.0  ...  3286.0  4352.0  3780.0  877634.20095
2    2020-11-12  2409.0  1765.0  3392.0  ...  3208.0  4305.0  3687.0  877634.20095
3    2020-11-13  2425.0  1770.0  3400.0  ...  3245.0  4322.5  3780.0  877634.20095
`

Answer (score 0):

> Solved using Join and then sum
>
> ```py
> for i in list(dfMerged.columns):
>    if i != 'Date':
>        index = (dfH[dfH["TICKER"]==i]["PPerc"].values[0] * dfMerged[i])
>        tmp = tmp.join(index,how="right")
>        
>        
> tmp["index"]=tmp.sum(axis=1)
> dfMerged["Ind"] = tmp['index']
> ```

*— @Billy101*